# Negative moments of Steinhaus random variables

Tags: pr.probability, moments, expectation, random-functions

Let $f_i, i=1, \ldots, n$ be independent Steinhaus random variables, i.e. variables which are  uniformly distributed on the complex unit circle. Let $a \in R^n$.

1) Find  $E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nf_i a_i\right)^{-k}$, for $k=1,2$

2) What would mean the following condition: $\|f\|_{\infty}> b \|f\|_2$, where $b<1$ and $\|f\|_{\infty}$ is the maximum part of the real parts of $f_i$